# How can find place referencing a js file?

Tags: google-chrome, hexo

I'm using **hexo** and **yilia** theme to build my blog,but when I visit my blog,I see some error on chrome console:

[image]

I want to change the two js reference to **https**,but I don't know where I can find the place referencing these files,anyone knows please help me,thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the **mathjax** js file, change it in [layout/_partial/mathjax.ejs](https://github.com/litten/hexo-theme-yilia/blob/master/layout/_partial/mathjax.ejs#L18)

For the **jquery** js file : change it in [layout/_partial/after-footer.ejs](https://github.com/litten/hexo-theme-yilia/blob/master/layout/_partial/after-footer.ejs#L18)

After that, don't forget to generate the new site with `hexo generate`